# Perform mean subtraction on a list of images?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a numpy array of shape `(100,320,320)`, 100 Images and each image is 320*320.

I tried doing:

```
mean = np.mean(train_x)
train_x -= mean
```

I get a `Cannot cast ufunc subtract output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'`

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like your  `train_x` is `uint8`, small integers.  `np.mean` with division produces a float.  It is saying that it can't put a float back into the `uint8` slot without loss of information.  So you need to tell it how to handle the misifit.

Comment: @KRKirov: Don't be misled - `np.int` is just another name for `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Either allow the result to be a floating point number:

```
mean = np.mean(train_x)
train_x = train_x - mean
```

Or calculate the mean as a `np.uint8` (which loses precision):

```
mean = np.mean(train_x, dtype=train_x.dtype)
train_x -= mean
```